# ConversationChain .run(), .predict(), .generate() will not accept context

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, langchain, large-language-model

I am leveraging hugginface and langchain to implement an in-house LLM. I am trying to pass in my question and context parameters into my ConversationChain object but it will not allow me to pass in more than one input. If it is a single input everything is functional.

However when there are two, whether it is passed in directly like this

```
conversation.run(input = input, context = context)
```

Or various dictionary formats like

```
inputs = {
    'input': input,
    'context': context
}

conversation.run(**inputs)
```

I receive a

`ValueError: One input key expected got ['input', 'context']`

This holds true even if I use .generate(), .predict(), or conversation()

I have tried to implement the workarounds presented [here](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/1800) by Bananenfraese and aigloss but ran into a whole new set of errors

I also went to the [Langchain Docs](https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/chains/langchain.chains.conversation.base.ConversationChain.html#langchain.chains.conversation.base.ConversationChain) and even they pass in context to the .run() function in the example. I do not know if the documentation has not been updated, or I need to use a different version of langchain (I am using the latest), but any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
# Suppose we have a multi-input chain that takes a 'question' string
# and 'context' string:
question = "What's the temperature in Boise, Idaho?"
context = "Weather report for Boise, Idaho on 07/03/23..."
chain.run(question=question, context=context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
print(chain.invoke({"context": context, "question":question}))
```

Here is the [documentation](https://python.langchain.com/docs/expression_language/interface)